# How to set order of layers when pushing "Save for All layers" in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins

I have two layers in PostGIS that are joined together. To make it simple, imagine layer tree and layer city. (See the ER diagram below).
Layer city is the 1 side and layer tree is the n side. (It is a one-to-many relationship)

[image]

If I add a city and a corresponding tree and push "Save for All Layers", both layers are saved. However, if layer tree is saved first, PostGIS produces an error saying that the city that this tree is joined is not in the database. If layer city is saved first, there is no problem.

Does anybody know if there is a way to manage the order of layers to be saved when pushing the button "Save for All Layers"?